# Notebook + external monitor = system crash

Tags: 11.04, multiple-monitors, monitor

I would like to use an external monitor with my HP Probok, but when I connect the cable to my notebook, it's screen turns black and the external screen starts to flicker pink and green. I use 11.04.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).